# PHP: Remove Text and Numbers after a Number Block (Include -> . <-)

Tags: php

can u help me? I try to create a little function and i dont know how to do it.

String: "GRUNDIG GWN 36630 Waschmaschine"
Output: "**GRUNDIG GWN 36630**"

Thats work with

```
$s2 = preg_replace("/([^0-9]*[0-9]*)(.*)/", "$1", $link->plaintext);
```

But if i have an String with dots inside like:
String: "WMF 12.7700.6343 Lingo 24-tlg. Besteck-Set"
The Output: "WMF 12"

But it should be **WMF 12.7700.6343**

I need a script that trim the String at the End of a Number block and not a the first numbers till first dot.

**Update: 09.09.2017**

sorry i dont know how to works with strackoverflow.

GRUNDIG GWN 36.6-30 Waschmaschine

WMF 12.7700.6343 **Lingo 24-tlg.** Besteck-Set

GIGASET C 430 **A Duo** Schnurloses Telefon

Should be:

GRUNDIG GWN 36.6-30 Waschmaschine
WMF 12.7700.6343 Lingo 24-tlg.
GIGASET C 430 A Duo

1. all words before a numer combination (ex. 19.23-2329)
2. after the words combination only add 2 words

GIGASET C 430 A Duo

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just have to search for `(^.+?([0-9.-]+)).*` and replace it with `$1`. That's it.

Here's a working live example with both of your strings:
https://regex101.com/r/6fLvpk/2

Comment: WOW Thank you! it works perfect! Nice Week! Thank you.. Thank youuu

Comment: Sure thing, have a nice week, too

Comment: So thanks for your help, but now i need a new answer. The regex works good but i need another :O. I updated the Text above

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: wait i just write down what i mean :D

Comment: sorry i dont know how to works with strackoverflow.

GRUNDIG GWN 36.6-30 Waschmaschine
WMF 12.7700.6343 Lingo 24-tlg. Besteck-Set
GIGASET C 430 A Duo Schnurloses Telefon 

Should be

GRUNDIG GWN 36.6-30 Waschmaschine
WMF 12.7700.6343 Lingo 24-tlg.
GIGASET C 430 A Duo

1. all words before a numer combination (ex. 19.23-2329)
2. after the words combination only add 2 words or 2 numbers

GIGASET C 430 A Duo

Comment: I only could do it just 1 word after the number combination https://regex101.com/r/Asvutu/1 but i need

a-1-9-Z whitespace a-1-Z-9